# Method Calling from header files

Tags: c++, function, methods, header-files

I have a programming assignment where I'm supposed to write up the code for inserting and removing linked lists. However I haven't used C++ in a while and am struggling remember certain things.

Right now, I am simply trying to put a prototype method in a header file, define it in my cpp file, and then call it in my main method. this is what I have.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {

public:
    void testPrint();
};
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

int main() {
    LinkedList::testPrint();

}

void LinkedList::testPrint() {
     cout << "Test" << endl;
}
```

I am getting the following errors

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
'LinkedList::testPrint': non-standard syntax; use & to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: To call a function like this `LinkedList::testPrint();` the function must be `static`.

Comment: you need an object to call a non-static member function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinkedList::testPrint()` is a member function.

It is not declared `static`, so that means it must be called on a particular object, defined as `LinkedList linked_list`, for example. Then use `linked_list.testPrint()`.

### Option 1 - `static` member function declaration

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {

public:
    static void testPrint();
};

int main() {
    LinkedList::testPrint();
}

void LinkedList::testPrint() {
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
```

### Option 2 - Instantiated object with call to member function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList {

public:
    void testPrint();
};

int main() {
    LinkedList linked_list;
    linked_list.testPrint();
}

void LinkedList::testPrint() {
    cout << "Test" << endl;
}
```